# OR instead of AND for SUMIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to calculate the number of hours spent in training as a grand total and as a total per staff member. I've built the following:

[image]

The second table is to track hours spent by individual staff members. I tried running a `SUMIFS` to check for if the staff member's name was in *either* the trainee *or* the trainer columns, but the conditions in `SUMIFS` must *all* be satisfied to add the value.

I also tried putting the two columns in one condition, but the number of columns in the conditions must match the sum columns, so that doesn't work either. For ease of reference I'd prefer to have these tables separate.

It is possible to have the same staff member in both columns at once, in which case I only want to add the hours once.

How can I collect a sum of values where *at least one* cell in its row contains a given value? Do I nest a `LOOKUP` in there somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the two `SUMIF` values together, then subtract the value when the same person is both Trainer and Trainee

```
=SUMIF(Table1[Trainee],[@Staff],Table1[Length])+SUMIF(Table1[Trainer],[@Staff],Table1[Length])-SUMIFS(Table1[Length],Table1[Trainee],[@Staff],Table1[Trainer],[@Staff])
```

Comment: There it is. I just worked this idea out, and was about to put it up here as an option to see if anyone could suggest something more elegant, but you've beaten me to it!

Comment: Elegance can be over-rated ;)